# Symfony 4 custom deserializer returns empty properties in entity

Tags: php, json, symfony, symfony4

I have a custom Symfony 4 deserializer

```
class CardImageDecoder implements EncoderInterface, DecoderInterface
{
    public function encode($data, $format, array $context = [])
    {
        if($format !== 'json') {
            throw new EncodingFormatNotSupportedException(sprintf('Format %s is not supported by encoder %s', $format, __CLASS__));
        }

        $result = json_encode($data);

        if(json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
            // don't bother with a custom error message
            throw new \Exception(sprintf('Unable to encode data, got error message: %s', json_last_error_msg()));
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function supportsEncoding($format)
    {
        return 'json' === $format;
    }

    public function decode($data, $format, array $context = [])
    {
        if($format !== 'array') {
            throw new DecodingFormatNotSupportedException(sprintf('Format %s is not supported by encoder %s', $format, __CLASS__));
        }

        if(!is_array($data)) {
            throw new \UnexpectedValueException(sprintf('Expected array got %s', gettype($data)));
        }

        $cardInstance = new CardImages();
        $cardInstance->setHeight($data['h'] ?? 0);
        $cardInstance->setPath($data['url'] ?? '');
        $cardInstance->setWidth($data['w'] ?? 0);

        return $cardInstance;
    }

    public function supportsDecoding($format)
    {
        return 'array' === $format;
    }
}
```

The way I'm deserializing is pretty straight forward:

```
$json = '
{
"url": "some url",
"h": 1004,
"w": 768
}';

$encoders = [new CardImageDecoder()];
$normalizers = [new ObjectNormalizer()];
$serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

$cardImage = $serializer->deserialize(json_decode($json, true), CardImages::class, 'array');

/** @var $cardImage CardImages */
var_dump($cardImage);
```

However, I get this result returned:

```
object(App\Entity\CardImages)#158 (5) {
  ["id":"App\Entity\CardImages":private]=>
  NULL
  ["path":"App\Entity\CardImages":private]=>
  NULL
  ["height":"App\Entity\CardImages":private]=>
  NULL
  ["width":"App\Entity\CardImages":private]=>
  NULL
  ["movie":"App\Entity\CardImages":private]=>
  NULL
}
```

Now, if I were to do a dump, just before the return in the `decode` part of the decoder, I'd get this:

```
...
$cardInstance->setWidth($data['w'] ?? 0);

var_dump($cardInstance);

object(App\Entity\CardImages)#153 (5) {
  ["id":"App\Entity\CardImages":private]=>
  NULL
  ["path":"App\Entity\CardImages":private]=>
  string(8) "some url"
  ["height":"App\Entity\CardImages":private]=>
  int(1004)
  ["width":"App\Entity\CardImages":private]=>
  int(768)
  ["movie":"App\Entity\CardImages":private]=>
  NULL
}
```

Ignoring the not set properties(which I'm fine with), it should work quite nicely, but it doesn't.

For the life of me I can't figure out what's wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have not much experience with the serializer component, but isn't an *encoder* meant to encode an *array*  into a format (json for example) and in reverse for decoding? however, you return an object, which I find odd. it probably should be an array. Normalizer (or Denormalizer to be precise) would be turning something into an object. Have you tried returning an array instead? as far as I can tell, you want a denormalizer but implement a decoder ... see graphic at: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html

Comment: why dont u use the `denormalizer` for converting your array/json to an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are thinking way to complicated.

Tested, working example:
Your entity - take a closer look at the end - we need setters with the names of your array keys:

```
namespace App\Domain;


class CardImages
{
    /** @var int|null */
    private $id;
    /** @var int|null */
    private $height;
    /** @var string|null */
    private $path;
    /** @var int|null */
    private $width;
    /** @var mixed */
    private $movie;

    /**
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param int|null $id
     * @return CardImages
     */
    public function setId(?int $id): CardImages
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getHeight(): ?int
    {
        return $this->height;
    }

    /**
     * @param int|null $height
     * @return CardImages
     */
    public function setHeight(?int $height): CardImages
    {
        $this->height = $height;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getPath(): ?string
    {
        return $this->path;
    }

    /**
     * @param string|null $path
     * @return CardImages
     */
    public function setPath(?string $path): CardImages
    {
        $this->path = $path;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getWidth(): ?int
    {
        return $this->width;
    }

    /**
     * @param int|null $width
     * @return CardImages
     */
    public function setWidth(?int $width): CardImages
    {
        $this->width = $width;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getMovie()
    {
        return $this->movie;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $movie
     * @return CardImages
     */
    public function setMovie($movie)
    {
        $this->movie = $movie;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setH(?int $height): CardImages
    {
        $this->setHeight($height);

        return $this;
    }

    public function setUrl(?string $url): CardImages
    {
        $this->setPath($url);
        return $this;
    }

    public function setW(?int $width): CardImages
    {
        $this->setWidth($width);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Simple Controller to test the Output:

```
<?php       
namespace App\Infrastructure\Web\Controller;

use App\Domain\CardImages;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerInterface;

/**
 * Class IndexController.
 *
 * @Route("/test")
 */
class TestController extends AbstractController
{
    private $serializer;

    public function __construct(SerializerInterface $serializer)
    {
        $this->serializer = $serializer;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("")
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function indexAction(): Response
    {
        $data = [
            [
                'h' => 100,
                'w' => 100,
                'path' => '/asdf/asdf.png',
            ],
            [
                'h' => 50,
                'w' => 150,
                'path' => '/asdf/foo.png',
            ],
            [
                'h' => 100,
                'w' => 200,
                'path' => '/asdf/bar.png',
            ],
            [
                'h' => 300,
                'w' => 400,
                'path' => '/asdf/baz.png',
            ],

        ];

        foreach ($data as $row) {
            $cardImage = $this->serializer->denormalize($row, CardImages::class, null, [
                ObjectNormalizer::DISABLE_TYPE_ENFORCEMENT => false
            ]);

            $json = $this->serializer->serialize($cardImage, 'json');

            dump($cardImage, $json);
        }

        return new Response('<html><head></head></html></body></html>');

    }
}
```

Output:
[image]